# Refreshing IG after save if validations pass

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with some data, when users add a new row it didnt show up(found that this is because I have written a custom procedure to save and I dont return the PK).

So I set up a dynamic action, on Save[Interactive Grid] with a server side condition Type: Inline Validation Errors NOT displayed, with a true action of Refresh region.

But the condition doesent appear to work.
When adding row which passes the validations, it refreshes just fine, but when adding a row that fails validations, the validation error shows up and a popup comes up asking if I am sure I want to procede as changes were made(tries to refresh).

I have tried changing the condition to Inline Validation Errors displayed, but that doesent work. I have tried changing Event scope to Dynamic(which I dont even know what it does), but that didnt help.

I also changed the IG primary key to ROWID from the default PK from my table if that might help with the custom save procedure.

I would prefer to fix this w/o editing the save procedure as if I have to I will need to fix up a LOT of save procedures. But if I cant I am willing to fix them. But I am not sure how.
My save procedure is formated as follows:

```
PROCEDURE save_table (s_variable1 IN table.variable1%TYPE
              , s_variable2 IN table.variable2%TYPE
              , row_status IN VARCHAR2)IS          
BEGIN
  CASE row_status
    WHEN 'C' THEN
      INSERT INTO table(variable1, variable2)
      VALUES (variable1_seq.nextval, s_variable2);

    WHEN 'U' THEN
      UPDATE table
         SET variable2= s_variable2
       WHERE variable1= s_variable1;

    WHEN 'D' THEN
      DELETE FROM table
       WHERE variable1= s_variable1;
  END CASE;

END save_table;
```

If someone could tell me the easiest way to fix this to return the PK(variable1) or ROWID so that the IG updates that one row so I dont even need the Dynamic Action.

EDIT:
Found the easiest way to do this is to change the procedure and found out how:

```
PROCEDURE save_table (s_variable1 IN OUT table.variable1%TYPE
              , s_variable2 IN table.variable2%TYPE
              , row_status IN VARCHAR2)IS
a_variable1 table.variable1%TYPE;          
BEGIN
  CASE row_status
    WHEN 'C' THEN
      a_variable1 := variable1_seq.nextval;
      INSERT INTO table(variable1, variable2)
      VALUES (a_variable1, s_variable2)
      RETURNING a_variable1 INTO s_variable1;
```

Only posted the section I changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RETURNING INTO clause allows us to return column values for rows affected by DML statements. You can use this in your procedure to return the column value as shown below.

```
 DECLARE
  l_id t1.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (t1_seq.nextval, 'FOUR')
  RETURNING id INTO l_id;
  COMMIT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ID=' || l_id);
END;
```

[For more details on `Returning into` see this link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause)

Comment: But would that require me to change the procedure into a function with a RETURN NUMBER?

Comment: You can return values in Procedure as well using OUT parameter

Comment: Yeah, I found that. I edited my question with the detailed answer I came up with so that if anyone else has the same question they get the answer that I found.
ty